# Access Control in Elastic - missing authentication credentials for REST request

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am using Elastic 7.9.2 version and wanted to use security.
so I ran :

```
bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert -out config/elastic-certificates.p12 -pass ""
```

and then added

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: elastic-certificates.p1
```

in `config/elasticsearch.yaml`

Now when I am running the ES by

```
 bin/elasticsearch
```

getting below error :

```
"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials
 for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-
8\""}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST 
request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-
8\""}},"status":401}root@ip-localhost:/var/log/elasticsearch
```

Can anyone please help!

Comment: Did you follow all the steps from the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-security.html), including creating the password for the built-in users? Also, what is in the elasticsearch log? The error you pasted is from a failed request. How did you made the request?

Answer (score 18):

Just pass authentication credential with url like below

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200" -u elastic:pass123
```

Answer (score 3):

I had security already enabled and user authentication working. Kibana loaded fine.

I have a 3 node cluster and stopped elasticsearch service on each node so I could add transport ssl.
After enabling `xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled` and keystore and truststore settings, I got the same ""missing authentication credentials for REST request" error in Kibana. Turns out the error was because I only had one node running and needed a minimum of two. After enabling transport ssl on another node and starting it, kibana worked again.

Answer (score 2):

To add the credentials to curl, you need to know them. [The root user is `elastic`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/built-in-users.html), the passwords can be reset using

```
bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords  auto
```

Then, you can use

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200" -u elastic:password_from_console
```

as [written above (go upvote)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71061935/1587329).

Comment: This appears to be the most useful answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
GET https://localhost:9200
Authorization: Basic elastic:{your user password}
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31279494)

Comment: @FranciscoPuga Please pay attention when reviewing. This is not a link-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable security for your cluster you & still got some error with AUTH yours clients, documentation wrote, what you need enable ssl for client optional OR required. Please, read the **original** topic: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/missing-authentication-for-rest-request/154807/13

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the credentials with your request with -u username:password